# React import all scss rules from a file into a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, sass

I'm trying to add the whole scss file into a React component.

I tried using styleName props but not succeed

```
import React from 'react'
import Calendar from 'calendar'

import { calendarStyles } from './calendar.scss'

const CalendarShift = () => <Calendar styleName={calendarStyles}/>

export default CalendarShift
```

Would like to know if its posible to "spread" all the scss rules from *calendar.scss* into *Calendar* component

Comment: What do you mean "spread"? EXPLAIN.

Comment: @zixuan what I meant with "spread" is if there is a way to use all _calendar.scss_ rules in Calendar component. Sorry I said "spread" because reminds me to the spread operator from ES6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to import the file and then use the class names like you will use them normally in a react component.

```
import React from 'react'
import Calendar from 'calendar'

import './calendar.scss'

const CalendarShift = () => <Calendar className="calendar"/>

export default CalendarShift
```

Note that you need a webpack loader for `scss` to work along with your react app.

In the case you wanted to use all the styles (class names) within your calendar component, you can still import the file in the file above and use the class names in the `Calendar`.

Another solution will be using a postcss sass extension to convert styles into objects so you can use them in object notation. Check this out https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss

Comment: So....I have plenty of classnames inside _calendar.scss_ and I would like to pass all at once , all together

Comment: Updated my answer with a postcss solution, I will suggest if you wanted to go that way, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy! Just use the github [postcss-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss) plugin and you can install it like this:

```
npm --save install postcss-scss
```

Or, if you prefer yarn:

```
yarn add --dev postcss-scss
```

You can check the github page for this plugin to get more information about it.

After installing, you can use your SCSS in object notation and use it like this:

```
const CalendarShift = () => <Calendar style={myStyle} />
```